# how to navigate from sibling component to another sibling component in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

Below is my `app.routing.ts`

```
export const Approute: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        component: DashboardComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'trip-details',
        component: TripDetailsComponent
      }
    ]
  },
  { path: 'not-found', component : NotFoundComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/not-found' }
 ];
```

`component.ts`

```
 viewDetails(details) {
     ...
    this.route.navigate(['../trip-details']);
  }
```

Above i have a component and am trying to navigate to another sibling component but am not able to navigate to `http://localhost:4200/home/trip-details` its redirecting me to `http://localhost:4200/not-found`.

Where am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify `relativeTo` which route as shown below:

```
import {Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
constructor(private r: ActivatedRoute) { }

viewDetails(details) {
    ...
    this.route.navigate(['../trip-details'], { relativeTo: this.r });
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

You should navigate like this:

```
this.route.navigate(['home', 'trip-details']);
```

Or, move trip-details one level higher in the routes, and then you can navigate to it directly with

```
this.route.navigate(['trip-details']);
```

Answer (score 2):

Because angular can not found the url as `../trip-details`

You should use `this.route.navigate(['/home/trip-details']);`

Juse add 'home' in front of the url