# Angular: Find Full URL String of Sibling Component in Routerlink

Tags: angular, typescript, angular10, routerlink

How do I find the full Url from a Router Link in Angular?
I know how to navigate to a sibling component, however looking for the full url string, to store in variable .

Resources:

[how to navigate from sibling component to another sibling component in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49487197/how-to-navigate-from-sibling-component-to-another-sibling-component-in-angular)

[How do I navigate to a parent route from a child route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37196882/how-do-i-navigate-to-a-parent-route-from-a-child-route)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following if you have the array of routes for your sibling route:

```
   this.router.serializeUrl(this.router.createUrlTree([...routes]))
```